# Unity does not load after installing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, 15.04

I performed a clean install of Ubuntu 15.04 on a Dell XPS 13, but Unity fails to load. After login I see only the desktop background and the mouse pointer but nothing else. Also, right and left clicking does not work and I cannot load a terminal.

I can start Unity by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, logging in and running `startx`, then right click and `Open Terminal` and then `Unity`, but that's not a solution. Also even if I do that I don't get the Menu Bar.

I tried pretty much everything I could find on Google to solve this, incl. making sure Unity plugin is [enabled on CompizConfig](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), reinstalling Ubuntu desktop and Unity or running `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` and then `setsid unity`, but nothing helped.

On Ubuntu 14.04 everything worked fine. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: @Pilot6 running lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' gives 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Dell Device 0665
 Kernel driver in use: i915

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after downgrading to Ubuntu 14.10 and upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04.